How to have my freighter's science specialist back?
The freighter has changed, again, and a few things have disappeared. I can build them again, not a big problem, but my Korvax science specialist is gone, too.
I built his science room again, but how to have him back? Do I have to hire another one?

I tried interacting with both my base's and my freighter's science terminal, always with the same message that I needed to hire a scientist. So my scientist was definitely gone.
Easy solution: I had an open secondary quest asking me to hire a Korvax in a different solar system. Once met, he took position at the science terminal in my base and I completed his missions without any problem.
Of course some of them were "old", since I received blueprints already owned, but everything now is working as expected.

Unless you were hit by a bug, the specialist should be back to their terminal after you build them again. If that is not the case, interacting with the built terminal should summon them.
If this still doesn't fix you issue, then maybe you can "force" the game to reset their position by summoning them at one of your bases (since they can't be on your base and the freighter at the same time, if their position on the freighter points to some invalid location, summoning them at your base may overwrite that).
If that still doesn't help, then hiring a new one would be worth trying, but I suspect that wouldn't work either ("hiring" a new one basically only replace their appearance but does nothing to their position or quest flags).
Sadly the specialist are one of the most bugged part of the game.
Completing a specialist quest chain should have them giving repeatable quests each day (for example the Exocraft specialist should mention racing to a given location, the farmer should ask for plants etc), yet... most players have them just end up in a "I should leave them work" state. Since that line is clearly programmed in the game, this almost seems intentional, making the real triggers quite obscure.
(For added context, soon after I got my Atlas Sceptre, the Weapon specialist stopped offering other multitools, and now is instead praising my current staff power. Weird...)

Oh, I didn't know I can only have one. I tried to "summon" him, but with no avail. I hired a scientist on the freighter months ago but I still have the mission to hire one for the base, so that probably means I have to hire him again in order to fix this.
